# OutputCaptureExtension and ParameterizedTest not working together

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit5

I've a test class having one `ParameterizedTest` with `CsvSource` and other tests using `CapturedOutput`. They run fine individually but fail randomly with `NoSuchElementException` when run together.
Following is the sample code:

```
@ExtendWith({MockitoExtension.class, OutputCaptureExtension.class})
class SampleTest {

    // Few Mocks and InjectMock

    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({"foo,hi-foo", "bar,hi-bar"})
    void someTest(String input, String output) {
        assertEquals(output, "hi-" + input);
    }

    @Test
    void anotherTest(CapturedOutput capturedOutput) {
        assertFalse(capturedOutput.getAll().contains("Checking some logs"));
    }

    @Test
    void lastTest(CapturedOutput capturedOutput) {
        assertFalse(capturedOutput.getAll().contains("Again checking some logs"));
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to resolve this issues?

PS: I can't create another test file.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue and interesting fix.

I was writing one Unit test which should have the CapturedOutput to assert on logs, and also work with @CsvSource.
My test looked like below

```
@ExtendWith({OutputCaptureExtension.class, MockitoExtension.class})
class SampleTest {


    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({"foo,hi-foo", "bar,hi-bar"})
    void someTest(final CapturedOutput output, final String input, final String output) {
        assertEquals(output, "hi-" + input);
        assert(output).contains("expected logs")
    }
```

However when I ran the unit test, I got below error.

```
Discovered multiple competing ParameterResolvers for parameter [final org.springframework.boot.test.system.CapturedOutput output] 

org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Discovered multiple competing ParameterResolvers for parameter [final org.springframework.boot.test.system.CapturedOutput output]
```

After banging my head for few minutes, tried reordering the parameters and it worked like a charm.

```
 @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({"foo,hi-foo", "bar,hi-bar"})
    void someTest(final String input, final String output,final CapturedOutput output) {
        assertEquals(output, "hi-" + input);
        assert(output).contains("expected logs")
    }
```

So, the learning here is, parameters for CSVSource should be provided first and CapturedOutput should be the last.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `Nested` class in JUnit5. I removed `OutputCaptureExtension` from root class and added that on top of `Nested` class and it worked fine.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SampleTest {

    // Few Mocks and InjectMock

    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({"foo,hi-foo", "bar,hi-bar"})
    void someTest(String input, String output) {
        assertEquals(output, "hi-" + input);
    }

    @Nested
    @ExtendWith(OutputCaptureExtension.class)
    class NestedTest {
        @Test
        void anotherTest(CapturedOutput capturedOutput) {
            assertFalse(capturedOutput.getAll().contains("Checking some logs"));
        }

        @Test
        void lastTest(CapturedOutput capturedOutput) {
            assertFalse(capturedOutput.getAll().contains("Again checking some logs"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why does this work?